# Include my close and reopen votes on the votes page (or the API /question object)

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, api, vote-to-reopen, information-display

The following URL only includes upvotes or downvotes that I have cast (as far as I can tell):

```
http://stackoverflow.com/posts/POST_ID/votes
```

**I'm requesting that this page also include the close and reopen votes that I've cast on the question.**

I realize that the timeline page includes information on who voted to close the question *after* it was closed, but that is not the information I am looking for.

I want to be able to find out the following without incurring a large overhead on requests:

- if *I* have voted to close a question *while it is still open*, or
- if *I* have voted to reopen a question *while it is still closed*

The timeline page returns a potentially large HTML response, while the votes page returns a relatively tiny JSON response.

---

**Alternative request**

The `/question` API object has the optional downvoted, upvoted, and favorited fields.

**Could the close_voted and reopen_voted (or however you want to name them) fields be added?**

Comment: Are you using some user script that accesses this information? I doubt very many users are even aware they can just look at this page, and just as few are going to know what the vote type IDs are. You can very easily tell if you've cast a close vote by just clicking on the close link and looking at the text. What overall benefit to the community would adding this to the output provide? Seems like a change that would help a very small fraction of a percentage.

Comment: Yeah I have a userscript that loads on a search page for close vote review requests in the [SO Close Vote Reviewers](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chat room. Right now it hides requests for closed / deleted questions and false positives (messages that aren't actually close vote review requests). I would like to be able to hide questions that the reviewer has already voted to close, but the close popup has rate-limiting which makes it useless for that purpose. As well, it is an overly large request for the information I'm trying to find anyway. @animuson

Comment: I would tend to consider that page an implementation detail, not a public API. You might wish to request that this information be added to the actual public API...

Comment: But, why not include it there? It should be pretty simple to do, and wouldn't adding it to the API be a larger undertaking? @Shog9

Comment: My point is, *you're asking for an API.* Assuming you don't want this implemented and then silently dropped at some point in the future, that is.

Comment: Updated with an alternative API request. I would much rather it be on the votes page for obvious simplicity reasons, but I would be OK with any easy way to obtain this information. @Shog9

Comment: I wasn't sure of a better place to write this so I'm commenting.  I noticed a lot of statistical analysis requests lately.  Most of the functionality is usually there already.  Perhaps a statistics segment including the API's would be well received in a dedicated place.

Answer (score 1):

Can't see why. We already have this information in the new timeline. [For example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/271867/timeline):

> [image]

Comment: I've edited my question to show that the timeline does not show the information that I am requesting to be shown, nor is it suitable for my needs because the response would be potentially large even if it did include the information that I am looking for.